# how to stop insertion of predefined html tags in textbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to stop user from inserting HTML tags while inserting text in the textbox, if user enters a text like `<b>test</b>` this should be consider as string completely, not as **test**.
For ex : We do here in StackOverflow, when we select the option of 'code sample'

Any suggestions.

**Edit**:  Here, I am able to save the string in `<b>test</b>` code format only, but when it is getting displayed, these tags are rendering as HTML tags, that is the text is getting bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a trick :

```
var html = $('#yourtextbox').val();
var divTmp = $('<div></div>').html(html);
var text = divTmp.text();
```

or in a single line

```
var text = escapeHtml($('<div>').html($('#yourtextbox').val()));
```

if You want to preserve the html code use this function

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Comment: but when it is getting rendered again, then those tags are getting considered as html tags, not the string. like writing >b>test</b> is getting saved as it is, but getting rendered as bold test

Comment: Mmmm i understand, you want to show the code.

You can tray with this function 

I edit the answer....

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stop the user from doing stupid things.

- You can add detections, as he types to indicate an error / or replace the text (using regexp)
- You can add "html5 form validation", but only works on supported browsers
- You can validate server-side (best option)
- You can clean up the mess client-side before submitting

Type as you go correction

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="correct(this)" />

function correct(ele) {
    ele.value = ele.value.replace(/[\<]/gi, "&lt;");
}
```

Example client-side stripTag function

```
    function stripTags(html) {
        var tmp = doc.createElement("div");
        tmp.innerHTML = html;

        var text = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
        return text.replace(/[\<\>]/gi, "");
    }
```

You'll probably want a variant of the above 2 ..or just do it server-side

Comment: Yeah, but using something else than regex would be perhaps nicer, such as jquerying the whole content. The jquery html interpreter > anything roll-your-own. Then you could do advanced processing for whitelisted tags and you could use the result during submitting.

Comment: Yes, I am using something of this kind only, but when it getting rendered again, then those tags are getting considered as html tags, not the string. like writing >b>test</b> is getting saved as it is, but getting rendered as bold test

Comment: No, still I guess u are not getting my question. for ex in a chat window, if u write <b>hi</b> click on enter, it will display it as bold hi not as a string, here in database it is saving as string only, but while rendering it is working as tag only.

Comment: You didn't formulate your question right then. "I want to save as-is (formatting included) in database, but display without html or with escaped html on the page" ..in which case it's the "display function" you need to look at and not the textbox entry.